In Google Sheets Having Trouble With the INDEX Command Not Returning Highest Value Item
When using the command =INDEX(A3:A8, MATCH(MAX(H3:H8),0)) It only returns the first value in the series, instead of the highest value. I'm not the most familliar with this command yet. This is just for a hypothetical buisiness for an assignment. (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QZe_NstvwTshY2vjiVeSNt2zBtpTnSPhv7dCDmyTYYw/edit#gid=0)
I've tried other commands but they're not fit for this specific chart. Looking up I cannot find any results either. I'm Expecting the command to return "Black Shirts" or "Attachable Sleeves" However it's returning "Blue Shirts"

sheet is private

if H3:H8 is numeric, try:
=INDEX(A3:A8, MAX(H3:H8))

or:
=FILTER(A3:A8, H3:H8=MAX(H3:H8))

